# Retrieve Image From Rackspace CloudFiles CDN-Enabled Container with C# API

Tags: c#, rackspace-cloud

I'm using [Rackspace Cloud Files API](https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles). I'm able to retrieve my images from a container which isn't CDN-enabled with the following code. When I try with a CDN-enabled one though, the container isn't found.

How do I retrieve files from a CDN-enabled container on Rackspace Cloud Files?

```
    var creds = new UserCredentials(username, api);
    var client = new CF_Client();
    Connection conn = new CF_Connection(creds, client);
    conn.Authenticate();

    var container = new CF_Container(conn, "TestContainer");
    var list = container.GetObjectList(true);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up, I spoke to a Rackspace rep. He clarified that this container was created on the Dallas end-point, while the API only pulls from the default endpoint, (Chicago). I ended up ditching the bindings API and went directly with the REST one. HTH.